# How to type mixing of caps and small letter in same textbox, if i set default uppercase in style?

Tags: php, html

I set default text as caps for textbox in style (**i.e., style="text-transform: uppercase"**) in html.

My Query is, 
i need to type mixing of caps and small letters in the textbox as like below,

***GLOBAL International PVT Ltd***

How can i do? Please anyone do me favour.

Comment: So.. what's the rule you need to follow?

Comment: Default textbox value should come in caps (i set text-transform as uppercase in style). If i want to enter small letter in-between the text **(ex. GLOBAL International PVT Ltd)**, i'll use shift key to change small case. it is possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for the answer is as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Change caps to small</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var bx, chr, indx, intvl, last, lng, ln2, str, tmp;
function PrepBox()
{
    bx = document.getElementById("txtbx");
    last = "";     //this will be the manipulated string
    lng = 0;       //its length
    intvl = setInterval("txtchk();", 100); //ten times per second
    return;
}
function txtchk()
{ 
tmp = bx.value;
ln2 = tmp.length;

if(ln2 < lng) //test for backspace
    last = tmp.substr(0,ln2);  //shorten the manipulated string

else if(ln2 > lng)
{ 
    str = tmp.substr(lng);   //get newly-typed character(s)

    for(indx=0; indx<str.length; indx++)  //for each one of them
    { 
        chr = str.charAt(indx);  
        if((chr >= "a") && (chr <= "z"))
            last += chr.toUpperCase();   //change lowercase to upper
        else  if((chr >= "A") && (chr <= "Z"))
            last += chr.toLowerCase();   //change uppercase to lower
        else
            last += chr;   //periods, commas, semicolons, ...
    }
}
lng = ln2;  //update saved-length of "last"
bx.value = last; //replace text in box with manipulated string
return;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="txtbx" size="50" maxlength="40" type="text" style="font-size:10pt;" onFocus="PrepBox();" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Output :**
*1. If caps lock is off, default typing text is caps, if i typing text with shift key pressing, it changed to small.*
*2. If caps lock is on, default typing text is small, if i typing text with shift key pressing, it changed to caps.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you want the default text-entry to be uppercase, but to allow lowercase when appropriate (as if the Caps Lock Key was locked).  Thus I suggest you don't specify the default style of all-caps.  You can use JavaScript to intercept the text being typed, and manipulate the text AS IF the caps-lock key was locked:

This is my complete (and since tested) test-page code (edited from my original answer, per my comments below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>test-page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
var bx, chr, indx, intvl, last, lng, ln2, str, tmp;

function PrepBox()
{ bx = document.getElementById("txtbx");
  bx.value = ""; //start with no text in box
  last = "";     //this will be the manipulated string
  lng = 0;       //its length
  intvl = setInterval("txtchk();", 100); //ten times per second
  return;
}

function txtchk()
{ tmp = bx.value;
  ln2 = tmp.length;
  if(ln2 < lng) //test for backspace
    last = tmp.substr(0,ln2);  //shorten the manipulated string
  else if(ln2 > lng)
  { str = tmp.substr(lng);      //get newly-typed character(s)
    for(indx=0; indx<str.length; indx++)  //for each one of them
    { chr = str.charAt(indx);             //get it
      if((chr >= "a") && (chr <= "z"))
        last += chr.toUpperCase();   //change lowercase to upper
      else if((chr >= "A") && (chr <= "Z"))
        last += chr.toLowerCase();   //change uppercase to lower
      else
        last += chr;   //periods, commas, semicolons, ...
  } }
  lng = ln2;  //update saved-length of "last"
  bx.value = last; //replace text in box with manipulated string
  return;
}

function ifenter(e)    //test for Enter key pressed
{ if((e.keyCode == 13) && (bx.value.length > 2)) //check minimum entry length
  { clearInterval(intvl);  //stop checking the box 10 times/second
    bx.blur(); //remove focus from box (ensures PrepBox() gets called for next entry)
    DoSomethingWithTheText(bx.value);
  }
  return;
}

function DoSomethingWithTheText(s)
{ tmp = document.createElement("span");
  tmp.innerHTML="<br />" + s;
  document.body.appendChild(tmp);  
  return;
}

// -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="txtbx" size="50" maxlength="40" type="text" style="font-size:10pt;" onfocus="PrepBox();" onkeydown="ifenter(event);" />


</body>
</html>
```

Note if the user presses/locks the Caps Lock key, this code will have the effect of manipulating the string in the text box as if that key had not been locked!  (And for anyone interested, that txtchk() function can be edited to do all sorts of interesting things; I usually use it to erase characters that I don't want the user to type.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
My requirement is

Example 1
HAPAG LLOYD INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED

Example 2
MAERSK INDIA Pvt ltd


Usually i type like **example 1** only.
In rare case, i need provision to type like **example 2**

Is there any possibilities to do like that?

Please note that i don't want use caps lock at all.

Comment: The code I offered should do exactly what you asked for, if the caps lock key is not pressed.  Everything you type in the text box is converted to uppercase if it starts out as lowercase --and if it starts out as uppercase (like when you hold the shift key down), those characters only are converted to lowercase.  Note the JavaScript code only affects text in the text box, and not text typed anywhere else (lowercase and uppercase will come through to those other places normally).

Comment: I used you code, but it converted into small case only (even if i try to enter caps). Basically, by default i type all the characters in caps only inside the textbox. If i need small case in-between the capital letters, by pressing shift key i type small letter. It is possible to do so???

Comment: I admit I didn't test the code before posting it, but it actually mostly works --that line beginning if((chr >= "A") should actually begin else if ((chr >="A") (I'm going to edit my code above to fix it; if you caught it and fixed it in your testing, good!)  The only other thing I can think of that might be causing a problem is if you still have that style="text-transform: uppercase" (or anything like that) associated with the text box.  Take it out!

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim Isn't this something you wrote? _This is my complete (and tested) test-page code:_

Comment: @Traian Tatic --I replaced my original and untested code with what you see here now.  The original code was not a complete web page; it only included just one line of HTML (the input line), and didn't include code for the DoSomethingWithTheText() function --the call was just a placeholder for whatever Barthee wanted to do with the entered text.  When Barthee said the JavaScript didn't work as I claimed, I had to test it, and so used it as the start-point for a test-page.  My previous comment here does say I would edit my originally-posted Answer --I simply did it thoroughly (grin).

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim: **thank you boss**. Finally I got the answer. I made a small changes in your code... Your code helps me a lot. Thank you again. :-)