# XSS safe html decode for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security, xss

I need to decode html in javascript. e.g.:

```
var str = 'apple &amp; banana';
var strDecoded = htmlDecode(str); // I expect 'apple & banana'
```

There is no guarantee that the given str is already encoded and common jquery and DOM tricks are XSS vulnerable:

```
var attackStr = '&amp;</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>&#x30cf;&#x30ed;&#x30fc;&#x30ef;&#x30fc;&#x30eb;&#x30c9;'; // if you see 1 alerted, it means it is XSS vulnerable
var strDecoded; // I wish to get: &</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>ハローワールド

strDecoded = $('<div/>').html(attackStr).text(); // vulnerable in all browsers

strDecoded = $('<textarea/>').html(attackStr).text(); // vulnerable in ie 9 and firefox


var dv = document.createElement('div');
dv.innerHTML = attackStr; // vulnerable in all browsers
strDecoded = dv.innerText;

var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
ta.innerHTML = attackStr; // vulnerable in ie 9 and firefox
strDecoded = ta.value;
```

Is there any XSS-safe way to html-decode?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish, exactly? The code that you show doesn't do HTML decoding at all, but HTML parsing.

Comment: Use innerText or jQuery .text() method instead of innerHTML/.html()

Comment: hopefully clarified the question

Comment: @daghan, how are you Obtaining the string that might be malicious? That could point the way for a best Answer.

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim, it is user input which sometimes comes encoded sometimes unencoded

Comment: If it is user input via a textbox or equivalent, then you can completely control what gets entered, thereby preventing much need to "decode" it afterward.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842070/how-to-type-mixing-of-caps-and-small-letter-in-same-textbox-if-i-set-default-up/25843571#25843571, and especially the last part of my Answer there.

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim Our business requirement: We do need a decoder to run with ANY string without executing javascripts in input. We have no luxury to sanitize what goes in.

Comment: @daghan, then I can't offer anything better.  You may have to write one from scratch.  But I suspect, as you do that, you will discover some things that malicious code-strings have in common, that you could more-efficiently block at the input stage (and not all business requirements stay set in stone when new relevant factors are discovered).  Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a mix of your code and the highest-voted (not the accepted) answer at [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode), how about this:

```
var decodeEntities = (function() {
  // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
  var element = document.createElement('textarea');

  function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      str = str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
      str = str.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }

  return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ursu67z6/

You could also have a look at https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he maybe. I haven't gone through it myself, but it might deal with some cases better. I expect that if you are only decoding rather than encoding, the dom-based approach is better.

Comment: very useful amalgamation

Answer (score 1):

> DOMPurify is a DOM-only, super-fast, uber-tolerant XSS sanitizer for
>   HTML, MathML and SVG. It's written in JavaScript and works in all
>   modern browsers (Safari, Opera (15+), Internet Explorer (9+), Firefox
>   and Chrome - as well as almost anything else using Blink or WebKit).
>   It doesn't break on IE6 or other legacy browsers. It simply does
>   nothing there.
>
> DOMPurify is written by security people who have vast background in
>   web attacks and XSS. Fear not.

I've tested and use DOMPurify and it's really good at sanitize untrusted data on client-side. Using is very simple.

Import the purify.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="purify.js"></script>
```

And call your untrusted variable.

```
var attackStr = '</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>'
var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(attackStr );
```

Output will be like following.

```
<img src="x">
```

You can test your XSS payload at here https://cure53.de/purify

Source codes, examples and documentations are can be found over here ( https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify )

Comment: I do not want to sanitize. I wish to keep the string as it is but just apply 1 level decode on it. Thus if my string is </textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>  it should stay as is. if it is &lt;</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>, it should be <</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)> etc. thx for lib anyways

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean solution that does not imply to inject the HTML anywhere. Copy both these functions somewhere in your code:
http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode/ and 
http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table/

You'll have to remove "this" in "html_entity_decode" on line 26.

```
console.log( html_entity_decode('&amp;</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>') );
// &</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>
```

Cheers.

-- **EDIT** --

Your textarea trick looks good, did it cover all your use cases ?

The only other javascript solution I think about is to use a sandboxed, same-domain, iframe. It gives me good results but would only work in recent web browsers... I post the code in case.

```
function safeHtmlDecode(str, callback)
{
    var sameDomainBlankPage = document.location.href; // This should be a blank html page located on same domain
    $iframe = $('<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin"/>').attr("src", sameDomainBlankPage);
    $iframe.on("load", function() {
        var body = $iframe.contents()[0].body;
        body.innerHTML = str;
        callback(body.innerText);
    });
    $("body").append($iframe);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var attackStr = '&amp;</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>&#x30cf;&#x30ed;&#x30fc;&#x30ef;&#x30fc;&#x30eb;&#x30c9;';
    safeHtmlDecode(attackStr, function(htmlString) {
        console.log( htmlString );
    });
});
```

Comment: nice reference, but for input:  &amp;</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>&#x30cf;&#x30ed;&#x30fc;&#x30ef;&#x30fc;&#x30eb;&#x30c9;   i need output:  &</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>ハローワールド  and it does not work.  get_html_transition_table is not comprehensive for everything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to safely display the content.

```
Use innerText or jQuery.text() method instead of innerHTML/.html()
```

Comment: I do not want to safely display the content. I wish to html-decode the string.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could get so far:

```
function htmlDecode(str){
    if(typeof str != "string") return str;
    str = str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
    str = str.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");     
    var ta = document.createElement("textarea");
    ta.innerHTML = str;
    return ta.value;        
}

//test:
var attackStr = '&amp;</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>&#x30cf;&#x30ed;&#x30fc;&#x30ef;&#x30fc;&#x30eb;&#x30c9;';
alert(htmlDecode(attackStr)); // &</textarea><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>ハローワールド
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery function like below, to encode or decode the input String

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}

htmlDecode('&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;')
// result "<b>test</b>"

htmlDecode('test')
// result "test"
```

In this code

1. I'm actually creating a Div which is not actually present on the page
2. Passing input string to the htmlDecode function
3. jQuery automatically encode/decode the string
4. Returning the new html/text

Hope this helps!

Comment: return $('<div/>').html(value).text();  -> this code is XSS vulnerable

Comment: .html() even executes <script> tags!

Comment: I tried:- const html = "<script>alert()</script>"; return $('<div/>').html(html).text(); and it did not give a popup (chrome)